# How to obtain a list of zones valid for given instance type?

Tags: amazon-ec2, boto3

Some cases require launching into a specific zone, but not all instances are in all zones. In particular `p3dn.24xlarge` instances are only present in 2 zones of Virginia.

Can someone recommend a way to get valid zones for an instance type using boto3?

When launching through UI I've been using "Spot Instance Pricing History" graph to figure which zones are allowed

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This snippet gives me the list of AZs that support an instance spot type (along with the price):

```
import boto3

instanceType = 'p3dn.24xlarge'
product = 'Linux/UNIX (Amazon VPC)'

for region in boto3.client('ec2').describe_regions()['Regions']:
    client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=region['RegionName'])
    for zone in [z['ZoneName'] for z in client.describe_availability_zones()['AvailabilityZones'] if z['State'] == 'available']:
        try:
            price = client.describe_spot_price_history(InstanceTypes=[instanceType],
                                                       MaxResults=1,
                                                       ProductDescriptions=[product],
                                                       AvailabilityZone=zone)['SpotPriceHistory'][0]['SpotPrice']
            print("%s: %s" % (zone, price))
        except IndexError: pass
```